# Need verification for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have three tables

Clients:

Client ID
First name
Last name

Transactions:
Trans ID
ClientID
RepresentativeID
Order ID
Representatives:

Representative ID
First name
Last name

I need to display all of the transactions information, with the representative name and client name that occurred in a specific date. Is this query right?

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM [Transactions], Clients.first name, Clients.last name,    Representatives.first name, Representatives. last name
  INNER JOIN [Clients]
  ON Transactions.ClientID= Clients.Client ID
  INNER JOIN [Representatives]
  ON Transactions.RepresntativeID = Representatives.Represntative ID
  WHERE Transactions.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-18' AND '1996-11-27';
```

Is that right or did i get all wrong?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use square braces, so the query is not correct for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Joining conditions are fine. However, depending on type of `OrderDate` column you may need to use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function, e.g.:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`OrderDate`,'%d-%m-%Y') 
BETWEEN '1996-09-18' AND '1996-11-27'
```

**Update**
We also need to update SELECT and FROM syntax:

```
SELECT t.Trans_ID, c.first name, c.last_name, r.first name, r.last_name
FROM Transactions t INNER JOIN Clients c on t.ClientID= c.Client_ID
INNER JOIN Representatives r
ON t.RepresntativeID = r.Represntative_ID
```

Comment: Is the intial select -                                                                                                  select FROM [Transactions], Clients.first name, Clients.last name,    Representatives.first name, Representatives. last name                    makes sense?

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look.. :)

Comment: Thanks! But I want to display all the columns from the Transactions table...is it wrong to start with "select * from transactions" and then the rest of the columns from other tables?